# Add more details in authconfig NextJs in Next-Auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth and using simple credentials to login , i am getting data in user which includes id, username, img, isAdmin but when i am accessing it in authconfig file using auth then i am only getting email which uses to authenticate user. but i want to create a check using isAdmin too.

auth.ts

```
export const { signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const user = await login(credentials);
          console.log("userData", user);
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any; user: any }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = (user as CustomUser).id;
        token.username = (user as CustomUser).username;
        token.img = (user as CustomUser).img;
        token.isAdmin = (user as CustomUser).isAdmin;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any; token: any }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user = {
          name: token.username,
          image: token.img,
          id: token.id,
          isAdmin: token.isAdmin,
        };
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

authconfig.ts

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard");
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [], // Add providers with an empty array for now
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

i want to create a check so that if isAdmin then go to /dashboard else go to /store